# Why my Golang pressure measuring tool and Apache Batch generate different number of ESTABLISHED links?

Tags: go, tcp

Apache Batch is a popular pressure measuring tool.

I write a tool with the same function in golang myself. Then I make some tests.
I find it works well.

But accidentally, I find a difference from my tool and Apache Batch:

When checking ESTABLISHED link number by the cmd `netstat -na|grep ESTABLISHED|wc -l`:

Use cmd `ab -n 128000 -c 128 http://127.0.0.1:8000/`, the cmd above returns a number near 128.

But use my own tool, the cmd returns near 256 (when set concurrency 128).

**Why my own tool have twice the expected number of concurrencies?**

My code:

```
func request(cli *http.Client, uri string) {
    resp, err := cli.Get(uri)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    if resp.StatusCode != 200 {
        panic("return" + strconv.Itoa(resp.StatusCode))
    }
}

func workRoutine(ch chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    cli := &http.Client{}
    for uri := range ch {
        request(cli, uri)
    }
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    rnum := 128
    tnum := 128000

    url := "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"

    ch := make(chan string)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < tnum; i++ {
            ch <- url
        }
        close(ch)
    }()

    wg.Add(rnum)
    for i := 0; i < rnum; i++ {
        go workRoutine(ch, &wg)
    }

    stime := time.Now()
    wg.Wait()
    dtime := time.Now().Sub(stime)
    fmt.Println("Timecost", dtime)
    fmt.Println("Throughputs", float64(tnum)/dtime.Seconds())
}
```

Comment: You should ask the author of fasthttp because that is what you are using.

Comment: @Volker Sorry I made a mistake of using third party package. Even with strandard library net/http, the problem is still there. I have edited.

Comment: You are instantiating a new http.Client for each and every request which is not what the documentation of http.Client recommends. You are working deliberately against the documentation and are astonished to see strange results? You do nothing to control keep alive and did not provide information about how ab does it. This type of measurements are not very scientific.

Comment: @Volker I chage the code and instantiate a client for each workRoutine but not each request. I just want to know why a request create 2 counts in the results of `netstat -na|grep ESTABLISHED|wc -l`

Comment: Then make a test without concurrency, establish one HTTP connection an monitor what netstat reports. If still unclear: Edit the question, remove the ab stuff and post the simplified code.

Comment: I get twice the number with `ab`, too. When I look at the output of `netstat`, I see two sockets for every connection: one `tcp`, another `tcp6` with the addresses swapped. Not sure what `tcp6` has to do with this, but the duplication itself seems correct, because netstat lists *sockets*, not *connections*.

Comment: Also note that your current code still doesn’t reuse connections, because you never read the response body (e.g. with [`ioutil.ReadAll`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll)), you just close it.